# python 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
def romberg(f,l):
    val=np.zeros(l)
    for i in range(0,l):
        h=2**(1-i)
        N=2/h
        val[i]=trapez(f,h,N)
    return val

def trapez(f,h,N):
    result=0                     
    stuetz=np.zeros(N+1);
    for j in range(0,N+1):
        stuetz[j]=0+j/N                  
    sum=0
    for k in range(1,N):                 #bilde summe von 1-N-1
        sum+=np.polyval(f,stuetz[k])
    a=np.polyval(f,0)*0.5*h
    b=(np.polyval(f,stuetz[N]))*0.5*h
    result=a+(h*sum)+b
    return result
```

main:

```
p=[1,0,0]
romberg(p,5)
```

error:

```
----> 3 romberg(p,5)

----> 7         val[i]=trapez(f,h,N)
```

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

how can i fix this please help me?
i appreciate it!

Comment: `N=int(2/h)` in your first function You need `N` to be an integer to be use in `range()`, so you have to explicitely tell the program you want `N` to be an integer.

Comment: oh man thank you so much now its working ! :-*

Answer (score 8):

change `N=2/h` to `N=2//h` to perform integer division.

```
def romberg(f,l):
    val=np.zeros(l)
    for i in range(0,l):
        h=2**(1-i)
        N=2//h
        val[i]=trapez(f,h,N)
    return val
```

**edit:**

You can also use `int(2/h)`

```
def romberg(f,l):
    val=np.zeros(l)
    for i in range(0,l):
        h=2**(1-i)
        N=int(2/h)
        val[i]=trapez(f,h,N)
    return val
```